# php syntax error using html table tags in php

Tags: php, html-table, syntax-error

there is a syntax error while i m trying to use html tags in php .....
and error is :

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\update.php on line 21"

```
echo"<table>
            <tr><th>sid</th><th>fname</th><th>lname</th></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="sid"></td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
        </table>";
```

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting here and you should see the issue. If you aren't using a text editor that shows that clearly you should change editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either escape the `"` double quotes or use `'` single quotes:

```
echo '<table>
            <tr><th>sid</th><th>fname</th><th>lname</th></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="sid"></td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
        </table>';
```

Also, I would suggest writing your html code outside of your php block.

Comment: thanks a lot bro ..... it was really helpful and cleared my query....